# Wrong(?) Glare reducers hat awarded?

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

A couple of minutes ago I enabled high-contrast on Stack Overflow to attempt and get the "Glare Reducers" hat (TBH: not a fan), and I just got it for Serverfault, which I haven't visited in several months (I just visited now to double check if I had some setting left there, which I haven't - but I got the hat before visiting it).

I guess this is a bug?

Comment: I didn't get the hat either (anywhere, I think)